# Модуль для постов WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Подскажите исходники, модуль позволяющий, после логина пользователя добавлять посты в закладки(для WP пишу)

Comment: Задайте вопрос так, чтобы вас можно было понять. Какие посты, в какие закладки. Приведите фрагмент кода, который вы пытались написать для решения этой задачи.

Comment: Нужно создать модуль, позволяющий, после логина пользователя добавлять посты в закладки. Добавить кнопку/иконку для каждой заметки в архивах, нажимая на которую заметка сохраняется. В меню добавить ссылку на страницу со списком добавленных постов (картинка, название, сокращенное описание). Посты из списка можно удалять.

Comment: я новичок в этом деле, подскажите в какую сторону "копать"

Comment: сохраняется - куда??? в какие закладки? браузера, что ли? в WordPress нет никаких закладок.

Comment: скорее всего да, в браузере, либо после регистрации добавлять к себе в закладки в кабинете, то что я выше скинул описание, так  мне скинули, вот сижу ломаю голову

Comment: данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что [вопросы о том, где найти программы, библиотеки, учебники по программированию и администрированию — не стоит задавать](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите плагин [CBX Bookmark](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cbxwpbookmark/).